# Javascript promise not works in for loop to present typing-effect

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, async-await, promise

I want the typing effect look like
"hi Phoebe"
"Today is a Great Day!"
each character appear one by one.

But the effect look like
"h" appears first, then "T" second.

I think the problem is "await animation" and "await wait" not working in for loop, but I don't know how to fix it :(

```
const contents =[{color:"white",content:"hi "},{color:"yellow",content:"Phoebe"}],
[{color:"white",content:"Today is"},{color:"yellow",content:"a Great Day!"}]

let spanNum=0

async function text(contents){
    spanNum++; 

    for(let i =0; i<contents.length; i++){
        
        const span = document.createElement("span");
        span.setAttribute("id",`a${i}${spanNum}`);
        
        const length = contents[i].content.length
        const content = contents[i].content;
        const selector = `a${i}${spanNum}`;
        
        let k=0
        await animation(k,length,selector,content)
        await wait();
                 
    }
}



function wait(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(resolve,600);
    });
}

function animation(k,length,selector,content){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{ 
        if(k<length){

            let c = content.charAt(k);
            console.log(c);
            document.getElementById(selector).innerText += c;  
            k++
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: `await` works just fine in a `for` loop. I see a few issues: 1. First and foremost, you're setting `k` to `0` on every loop iteration. 2. There's no reason for `animation` to be wrapped in a promise, as it doesn't do anything asynchronous. 3. You're only looping through `contents`, not `content`. 4. The `k++` in `animation` has no effect, since you're just updating the local parameter, which has no effect at all on the `k` in `text`. 5. You never put `span` in the DOM that I can see.

Comment: Once you've fixed the issues above, if you still have further issues and need to ask a new question, please make sure to include a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).